# How to include Web.config in the TFS 2015 Contents section

Tags: tfs, build, visual-studio-2015, web-config

I am trying to produce artifacts with TFS 2015.

Everything works fine except it does not include my Web.config file, which is vital to our application.

How can I get TFS to include my Web.config file in the "contents" area of the "Publish Build Artifacts" step of our build?

I have tried:

```
Web.config
*.*.config
*.*.xml
**\.xml
```

These are working:

```
**\bin
**\Content
**\fonts
**\Models
**\Scripts
**\Views
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `*.config`

Did you really want to exclude any files?  If not `**` should include everything in the root.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce what our Publish settings do (as if you manually publish from VS.NET 2015).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reproduce what you can do when publishing from Visual Studio the  you need to pass the correct MSBuild options to create the msdeoloy .zip file. You can the. Mearly capture *.zip...

Enter: “/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"” in the MS Build arguments…

When you build the output should include the same output in a zip as is created from the VS ui. You can also pass publish profiles and other parameters.